# Cannot start recv'ing chunk, sharding is not enabled and no config server was provided

Tags: mongodb

I config a cluster in MongoDB as following:

1 Config Server 
2 Shard Servers,

and this is Sharding status:

```
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("59c333c5d92439c17b08a330")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/ShardServer1:27018",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ "siteGroup1" ] }
        {  "_id" : "rs2",  "host" : "rs2/ShardServer2:27018",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ "siteGroup2" ] }
  active mongoses:
        "3.4.9" : 2
 autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
                Balancer lock taken at Thu Sep 21 2017 05:39:18 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Standard Time) by ConfigServer:Balancer
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                195 : Failed with error 'aborted', from rs2 to rs1
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "DataCollector",  "primary" : "rs2",  "partitioned" : true }
                DataCollector.EMessageData
                        shard key: { "SiteId" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                rs2     5
                        { "SiteId" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "SiteId" : 1 } on : rs2 Timestamp(1, 1)
                        { "SiteId" : 1 } -->> { "SiteId" : 10 } on : rs2 Timestamp(1, 2)
                        { "SiteId" : 10 } -->> { "SiteId" : 11 } on : rs2 Timestamp(1, 4)
                        { "SiteId" : 11 } -->> { "SiteId" : 20 } on : rs2 Timestamp(1, 5)
                        { "SiteId" : 20 } -->> { "SiteId" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs2 Timestamp(1, 6)
                         tag: siteGroup1  { "SiteId" : 1 } -->> { "SiteId" : 10 }
                         tag: siteGroup2  { "SiteId" : 11 } -->> { "SiteId" : 20 }
```

When I move a chunk from a Shard Server to another and got the error message: 
"cannot start recv'ing chunk, sharding is not enabled and no config server was provided"

Could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advanced!

Updated:
Config Server log says:

```
2017-09-22T03:48:32.803+0200 I SHARDING [Balancer] distributed lock 'DataCollector.EMessageData' acquired for 'Migrating chunk(s) in collection DataCollector.EMessageData', ts : 59c46aefbd78955b52702afc
2017-09-22T03:48:32.809+0200 W SHARDING [conn5] cannot start recv'ing chunk, sharding is not enabled and no config server was provided
2017-09-22T03:48:32.817+0200 I SHARDING [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] distributed lock with ts: '59c46aefbd78955b52702afc' and _id: 'DataCollector.EMessageData' unlocked.
2017-09-22T03:48:32.820+0200 I SHARDING [Balancer] Balancer move DataCollector.EMessageData: [{ SiteId: 1.0 }, { SiteId: 10.0 }), from rs2, to rs1 failed :: caused by :: UnknownError: cannot start recv'ing chunk, sharding is not enabled and no config server was provided
2017-09-22T03:48:32.820+0200 I SHARDING [Balancer] about to log metadata event into actionlog: { _id: "ELVN-LAP02-2017-09-22T03:48:32.820+0200-59c46bf0bd78955b52702dcf", server: "ELVN-LAP02", clientAddr: "", time: new Date(1506044912820), what: "balancer.round", ns: "", details: { executionTimeMillis: 31, errorOccured: false, candidateChunks: 1, chunksMoved: 0 } }
```

Log file of nodes:
https://github.com/jvanhien/mongodbcluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutdown all mongod and mongos (those two) processes, your shards and that config server. When nothing is running, first start shardServers when those are up, start config server and last mongos. Connect to mongos with mongo.

I noticed that with your tags, you haven't define where $minkey --> 1, SiteId: 10 or SiteId:20 --> $maxKey goes. So those chunks can be anywhere.

When chunkMove happens, what config servers log says?

Comment: I did steps as you guided, and this problem still happen. and I updated question with config servers log says.

Comment: Have you checked that there are NO firewalls between nodes and config servers? Ports 27017, 27018, 27019 are open between all players in the cluster!

Comment: I allowed all inbound and outbound connections for Domain, Private and Public Profiles for all nodes in this cluster.

Comment: Is there some other error messages in mongod/mongos log files (data nodes primary and config server primary node).

Comment: I added log files for all nodes to github repository. Could you please see the update of Question. Many thanks!

Comment: What an IP address mess. It looks like that you have two IP addresses on shardedServer2, .1.107 and .1.75, "planning" so that replica set is at .107 and mongos .75, BUT name server resolves name shardedServer2 to BOTH addresses.  One IP address to one server OR use IP addresses at replica set configurations (not host names). Then you could rename that config servers replica set to confRS (or something, BUT not rs1 because your shardServer1 is already rs1)

Comment: I have one config server with IP is 1.107 and two shard servers with IPs are 1.75 and 1.49 and 2 mongos on these shard servers. I will test with case rename replicateSet name for config server and let you know later. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate name of replication sets is a problem. I have the same replication set name 'rs1' for both Config and Shard Server. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem!